# When in Visual Studio Data Tools, can I impersonate another domain user for a connectin manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have an SSIS project opened in Visual Studio 2012 Data Tools, and it uses several connections to source- and destination databases. We have a domain service account that has access to these data sources.

**How can I configure the connection managers inside VSDT to use that service account?**

I must use integrated security, because the source database doesn't accept mixed-mode authentications and I must run VSDT under my own domain user to avoid conflicts with TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question - you cannot. In Connection Manager you either use integrated security with underlying account or login/password for mixed security.

Workaround for your situation. Develop packages, build and commit in VSDT under your account. For testing only run another copy of VSDT under designated service account; this account should have enough privileges to open your SSIS project and run it.